# Spring-boot, How to replace the id value to the respective entity's any desired field name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am working on an existing database and I am not allowed to modify any table.

*I have the following entity:*
**PostCharge Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data // from lombok
@AllArgsConstructor // from lombok
@NoArgsConstructor // from lombok
public class postCharge {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String cat;
    private Integer catId;   
    private String code;
}
```

Now, I have **3 different tables named: Cat1, Cat2, and Cat3.** The field cat will hold the value like c1 or c2 or c3 to identity the table and **catId** will hold the **ID** of the object from the selected cat table.

*I have the following EntityDTO (using MapStruct)*:
**PostChargeDTO**

```
@Entity
@Data // from lombok
public class postChargeDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String cat;
    private Integer catId;   
}
```

**DTO Mapper**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PostChargeMapper {
   List<PostChargeDTO> postChargeToDTOList(List<PostCharge> postCharges);
}
```

**PostChargeRespositoty**

```
@Repository
public interface PostChargeRepository extends JpaRepository<PostCharge, Integer> {

    List<PostCharge> findAllByCat(String cat);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class PostChargeService {
    @Autowired
    private PostChargeRepository postChargeRepository;

    public List<PostCharge> fetchPostChargeList(String cat) {
        return postChargeRepository.findAllByCat(cat);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/post-charge")
public class PostChargeController {
    @Autowired
    private PostChargeService postChargeService;

    @Autowired
    private PostChargeMapper postChargeMapper;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<PostChargeDTO> fetchPostChargeList(
            @RequestParam(name = "cat") String cat) {
        return postChargeMapper.postChargeToDTOList(postChargeService.fetchPostChargeList(cat));
    }
}
```

**List Response**

```
{
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cat": "c1",
    "catId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "cat": "c2",
    "catId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cat": "c1",
    "catId": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cat": "c3",
    "catId": 5
  },
}
```

Now how do I replace the **catId value** with the **value from any other column** from the **respective cat table**?

Like if table c3 with catId 5 has a column named as the title with the value "foo". How do I get this "foo" to display in that JSON in the respective object?

So instead of "catId": 5, I want to get "catId": "foo" or maybe a new key with the value if needed to achieve the result.

I am new to spring-boot and Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@JsonProperty` annotation in your dto class:

```
@Entity
@Data // from lombok
public class postChargeDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String cat;
    @JsonProperty("foo")
    private Integer catId;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get this, how will @JsonProperty("foo") change the value of the key catId to "foo" ? And why the @Entity annotation for DTO class ?

I think you didn't get my final question, I have updated it with a small example.

Comment: I just used your PostChargeDTO class, you put the `@Entity` yourself :), the key is `@JsonProperty` annotation

Comment: Sorry, my mistake about the ````@Entity````. So if i am not wrong, ````@JsonProperty```` will only change the key catId to Foo and not get the actual desired value from the respective cat table.